# What parameters do you use to find the order in which elements will leave a solution during electrolysis?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, elements, reduction-potential

I am looking to perform electrolysis on a molten solution of many elements, specifically a mix of iron, sodium, potassium, silicon, aluminum, and titanium oxides and chlorides. What I'm trying to figure out is how to determine what order the elements will be reduced in, and how this is determined. Some ideas I have are to base it off of the electronegativities or the Gibbs energies, but I'm not sure how feasible calculating the Gibbs energies even is in such a messy solution.

What parameters or formulas would be used to determine this?

Comment: The published potentials are valid for aqueous solutions. They are not valid for molten and anhydrous solutions like here. I am afraid you would have to establish this order yourself by trails and errors. .

Comment: You might research what others have found in similar experiments, e.g., http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/98589 or https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268400452_Direct_Electrolysis_of_Molten_Lunar_Regolith_for_the_Production_of_Oxygen_and_Metals_on_the_Moon , or even contact authors directly.